# How to identify any sequence of unique numbers from the range 0 to 100

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve a problem which requires a way to generate a key, ie, identify uniquely a sequence of unique numbers from the range 0 to 100.  An individual sequence will not contain duplicate numbers. I thought, by intuition, that concatenating the count of numbers in the sequence and the sum of numbers in the sequence would produce a number that would uniquely identify that sequence, however I am not sure if this is true, or how to go about proving it.

For Example:
{0,2,3,6,7} = 518

{5,8,9,10,16} = 548

{18,26,29,33,59,71} = 6236

Comment: Not sure I follow.  For your first example, you get $518$ because your sequence has five terms and $0+2+3+6+7=18$?  But what would you get for the sequence $\{0,1,4,6,7\}$?

Comment: There are dumb ways to do what you want.  Let $p_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ prime and then, for your sequence $A=\{a_i\}$ define $F(A)=\prod_{n=1}^{100}p_i^{\delta_i}$ where $\delta_i=1$ if $i \in A$ and $=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Trouble is, you've got $2^100$ possible sequences. Basically, I can't think of any other way than with a 100 bit binary number, the $n$th bit being 1 if n is in the sequence & zero if it is not. That is ... assuming the sequences are truly arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not do it.  $(5,8,9,11,15)$ produces the same count and sum of $648$.  If the sequence is in increasing order or you just care about which numbers are there, there are $2^{101}\approx 2.5\cdot 10^30$ possible sequences, so you need at least $31$ digits in your number to identify them all.

The simplest is just to create a $101$ bit binary number with a $1$ for all the numbers that are present and $0$ for all the numbers that are missing.  This would be called the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of your subset.

Comment: thank you.. this is the simplest way to do it.